# How do I make this method under Leaflet's onEachFeature produce a different result if GeoJson property is empty?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm new at this, so excuse me if my vocabulary isn't very exact.

I can't get this code to work properly. When the name property of my GeoJson is filled, I'd like to have a popup that reads "The average temperature of (name) from 1993 to 2011: (temp)". And then when the name property of my GeoJSON is empty, have it read: "The average temperature of this unnamed stream from 1993 to 2011: (temp)".

```
let onEachFeatureA = function (feature, layer) {
     let name = feature.properties.GNIS_NAME
     if (name == '') {
          name = 'this unnamed stream'
               }
     let temp = feature.properties.S1_93_11
     layer.bindPopup('The average temperature of ' + name + ' from 1993 to 2011: ' + temp + '<br>The ideal water temperature for Chinook salmon ranges from 12.8 to 17.8 degrees Celsius.');

 }
```

The code results in a line reading "The average temperature of from 1993 to 2011: (temp)".

Comment: I think you're confused between an empty string and javascript's [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) (which is what one gets when trying to access a non-existent object property. It'd be nice to have a look at some relevant pieces of the GeoJSON data just to be sure.

Comment: Feel free to look at the JavaScript: https://mlinto34046.github.io/final/final.js or have a look at my project page on Github with all of the files: https://github.com/mlinto34046/mlinto34046.github.io/tree/master/final